# Eclipse Pydev interactive console use inside functions

Tags: pydev

What are the best practices for developing with the Eclipse Pydev interactive console once code migrates inside a function?

I heavily use the interactive console as my projects are typically experimental, open-ended, and not spec-driven.  The interactive console works well for code in the main loop, but as soon as I migrate that code to a function, I only know to use breakpoints with the debug view.  However, that seems unwieldy, and I don't need the entire stack, nor error-catching mechanisms.

Is there a way to have the vanilla pydev environment interactive console inside a function, for example on the first breakpoint, or raised error?

Without this, I typically have to copy the function back into the main loop.  Then, I end up using the same variable names, which leads to occasional global variable name accidents when I copy back to a function.

Thanks in advance.